# Add files to a docker image using a loop

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a script that creates several files starting with part_, and I would like to create a for loop inside the Dockerfile to search the directory for files starting with part_ and ADD them to the docker image. It is important to ADD each file as a separate layer (and not using wildcards like `ADD part_* /directory/`). How can I dynamically add files to a docker image?

I would like to use something like the `RUN for f in part_*; do ADD $f /data/; done`, but I do not know how I can incorporate ADD inside the bash script.

Here is an example of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD part_aa /directory/
ADD part_ab /directory/
ADD part_ac /directory/
ADD part_ad /directory/
ADD part_ae /directory/
ADD part_af /directory/

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

CMD entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use scripting to create your Dockerfile;

```
echo "FROM ubuntu:20.04" > Dockerfile
echo "RUN apt-get update && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" >> Dockerfile

for f in part_*; do echo "ADD $f /data/" >> Dockerfile; done

echo "COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/" >> Dockerfile
echo "CMD entrypoint.sh" >> Dockerfile
```

Comment: It's automated breaking of the DRY principle:)

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) directive (and `ADD`, but you should usually prefer `COPY`) understands ordinary shell globs, so you can just

```sh
COPY part_* .
```

(If these files came from the **split**(1) command, and you're just going to **cat**(1) them together, it will probably be easier and substantially smaller to combine them on the host before you `docker build` the image; `RUN rm` never actually makes an image smaller so your image size will include both the size of the parts and the size of the combined file.)